# Can't get Django admin to find static files (css, img, js) on Apache

Tags: python, django, apache, localhost, admin

I'm creating a Django development environment on my mac, and the admin is not finding the media files for styling. This is my settings.py file:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/Users/username/Projects/django/cake/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

This is the URL I go to, `http://127.0.0.1/admin/`, and the login section shows up just fine. There is no styling, however.

I copied the files over from the `sitepackages/django/contrib/admin/media/` directory to `/Users/username/Projects/django/cake/static/admin/` via:

```
cp -r /Users/username/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/ ./
```

I can see the files are there.

### EDIT

I just looked at the source and this is the path used for the css: `href="/static/admin/css/base.css"` So, that should be the problem. How would I fix this? Doesn't admin already handle adding the static_url to the admin_media_prefix?

### EDIT 2

If I hardcode the fullpath in `admin_media_prefix` it still doesn't use the stylesheets.

Inside my settings.py:

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/Users/username/Projects/django/cake/static/admin/'
```

And the source code shows:

```
href="/Users/username/Projects/django/cake/static/admin/css/base.css"
```

And when I go to that directory the CSS files are there...

### EDIT 3

These are in my apache config:

```
Alias /site_media/ /Users/username/Projects/django/cake/media
Alias /static/ /Users/username/Projects/django/cake/static
Alias /media/ /Users/username/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media
```

Comment: What version of Django are you using? ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX was removed (or deprecated) in 1.4 I believe.

Comment: @jefffabiny Did you get this working or not?

Answer (score 3):

> I copied the files over from the sitepackages/django/contrib/admin
>   directory to /Users/username/Projects/django/cake/static/admin. I can
>   see the files are there.

There's no need to copy all the files in `sitepackages/django/contrib/admin`. Just copy the directory `sitepackages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin` with...

```
cp -R /path/to/sitepackages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin /Users/username/Projects/django/cake/static
```

...or if you don't intend to change the admin pages, a symlink will suffice...

```
ln -s /path/to/sitepackages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin /Users/username/Projects/django/cake/static
```

---

**Update**

> I don't use the django development server; I'm running apache.

The `/static/` directory is automatically handled by the Django development server, but if you're trying to do this via apache, you'll have to add an `Alias` directive in you apache config, along the lines of...

```
Alias /static /Users/username/Projects/django/cake/static
```

It's covered in the [deployment docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files), although while you're developing, it's much easier to use the built-in development server, since it automatically restarts whenever you change any of your source files.

If you're using apache with mod_wsgi, then you'll have to manually restart apache every time you change a source file.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I was just making a reference to that directory, but what you outlined above was what I actually did.

Comment: @jefffabiny So your `/Users/username/Projects/django/cake/static/admin` contains the three directories: `css`, `img`, and `js`?

Comment: @jefffabiny Strange. I'm sure that used to work for me, although I didn't used virtualenv. Maybe reading [ticket #8336](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8336) would help?

Comment: I don't use the django development server; I'm running apache.

Comment: I have some aliasing set up already, perhaps they are wrong... they are in my 3rd edit.

Comment: @jefffabiny IIRC, for `Alias foo bar` if `foo` ends with a slash, then `bar` should also, and if `foo` doesn't end with a slash then `bar` shouldn't either. Try `Alias /static/ /Users/username/Projects/django/cake/static/`

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the permissions of your copied admin files. Are they permissioned the same way as your other static files that are being successfully accessed?
2. Check the load error you are getting in your Browser's debugger (is it 404 or something else)
3. Are you using django's manager.py command collectstatic? That's what I use to collect the static files in a directory. See [Django collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic)

Answer (score 0):

My solution to connect the Django Admin CSS in production is:

**/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
Alias /static/ /home/aaron/public_html/samapet.com/kennel/static/
<Location "/static/">
    Options -Indexes
</Location>
```

**in settings.py**

```
STATIC_ROOT = /home/aaron/public_html/samapet.com/kennel/static/ # Path to Static Dir
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**important, don't forget**

then run `./manage.py collectstatic` in production server SSH shell.

done!

Answer (score 0):

I got simple solution, I looked at the access_log files inside /var/log/httpd/

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Dec/2013:14:49:20 -0500] "GET /static/admin/css/login.css HTTP/1.1" 200 836 "http://127.0.0.1/admin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.24) Gecko/20111109 CentOS/3.6.24-3.el6.centos Firefox/3.6.24"
```

So configured static path in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file using,

```
Alias /static /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static
```

inside `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>` tag,

then I restarted service using

service httpd restart

and it **Works!!!**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but `python manage.py collectstatic` didn't solve my problem, so i had to copy css files directly to my static folder !

```
$path_to_my_app/static$ tree -L 1
.
├── css
├── fonts
└── js
```

using my config(ubuntu 12.04 and python 2.7), the directory the directory of admin css and js static files was here:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static
```

then I copied admin folder from above path to static path of my app, and so it looked like this:

```
.
├── admin
├── css
├── fonts
└── js
```

this worked for me.